# SQL table creation

Tags: sql, oracle, filter, ddl

I want to create a table by filtering by a particular age group. There are 4 age groups in my database = 18-24,25-39,40-65, 65+. The data looks like this:

```
Name             AgeRange
abc              18-24
xyz              25-39
axa              18-24
```

I am interested in the young age group. I am using the following but it creates a blank table

```
create table NEW_18_24 as select * from table where AGERANGE like '%18-24%';
```

Comment: _"it wouldn't just work"_ Why not? What happened? Did you get an error? What was it?

Comment: It creates a blank table.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Check the hyphen `-` carefully. It might be mistaken with dashes. `‒, –, —, ―`. Try `select DUMP(AgeRange, 1016) FROM ...`

Comment: Your code should work.  You must have some unusual characters -- for instance, the hyphens don't match.

Comment: Missing from? In source table? Select * where... Where is the from?

Comment: I am not missing the from - if i did it wouldnt create a blank table

Comment: Thank you @WernfriedDomscheit - it was the dashes

Comment: Maybe a collation thing, case sensitivity. In your example casing doesn't match. AgeRange versus AGERANGE

Comment: Column names in Oracle are not case-sensitive - unless you write `where "AGERANGE" like '%18-24%'` - but then you would get a different error.

Comment: If not the hypen issue (which I see it is) , how about "AGERANGE" like '%18%24%' or  "AGERANGE" like '18%24'?  Unless you're expecting age range to have values like '180-240' etc.